# No route matches [GET] "/js/vendor/jquery.js"

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, zurb-foundation-5

I'm getting the following error, but my server is still running and I don't get an error page rendered. I came across this while attempting to troubleshoot Foundation 5 top-bar drop-down (which won't display).

I'm very new to Rails and the like. Please play nice. :)

```
Started GET "/js/vendor/jquery.js" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-06-08 23:36:25 -0700

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/js/vendor/jquery.js"):
  actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:21:in `call' actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
  railties (4.2.1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
  railties (4.2.1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'

  ...(continues to display entire stack)

  bin/spring:13:in `<top (required)>'
  bin/rails:3:in `load'
  bin/rails:3:in `<main>'
```

Comment: please add some more details

Comment: Add you add your routes.rb file. Your getting an error in your routes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer to this problem. I had followed another answer to a question involving the top-bar in Foundation 5, which told to add the line:

```
<script>javascript_include_tag "js/vendor/jquery.js"
```

...I removed that line from my application.html.erb